# Install tmakin/TypedJSON in angular-cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I tried install https://github.com/tmakin/TypedJSON on an angular-cli project but I don't know how to install the typings appropriately.

When the typings are needed on angular-cli I did something like:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/moment
```

But in this case, the readme says to do:

```
typings install npm:typedjson-npm
```

This does not work because it creates a typings/ folder instead of install it on node_modules/@types/ (I think the typings should be here).

I did a build but I get the following warning:

```
WARNING in ./~/typedjson/js/typed-json.js
25:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
```

In addition, on browser console appears the next error:

```
typed-json.js:25Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
```

How should I install the typings?